# Whitelist certain email addresses in postfix

Tags: email, gmail, postfix-mta

I'm trying to work out how to have postfix only allow emails through to certain email addresses.

I had it working using the following config:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access, reject
```

and then access contains

```
example1.com                OK
example2.com                OK
miles@example3.com          OK
```

This worked - mail to anything that wasn't in the whitelist was rejected by the mailserver.

I then wanted to route all my outgoing mail via gmail, so added

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

It now seems that postfix is ignoring the whitelist, and sending everything through to the gmail servers.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and what I might need to do to resolve this?

**In short - I'd like all my mail sent via a gmail account, but only if the recipient address is in a whitelist.**

Answer (score 0):

Show some logs please.

I suspect that you are sending emails via `/usr/bin/sendmail` or `postdrop`. Both these commands bypass the smtpd and so the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, as they delivery the locally to the postfix, not via network.

If the sent email arrived via network (and so via smtpd) then show the config too (`postconf -n`) as you may have other configs that are changing the final result for those emails.